STUSB4500: Can someone please help me understand this diode/capacitor/resistor network in the datasheet?
I am working on a circuit that uses an STUSB4500 to negotiate USB-PD to power the system. I have it working without issue at the moment, but this little bit on the reference schematic from the datasheet has me scratching my head a bit. I am talking about the part circled in red here, D4, C4, R1 and R4 from Figure 10. Typical schematic with MCU in the datasheet:

I at least believe that I understand the function of the discharge circuit, but I'm not really sure what this part is achieving so maybe I don't.  Many other designs that I have found actually just replace these components with a single resistor between Vbus and the VBUS_VS_Disch pin and leave it at that. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?
